# Using Zurb Foundation's data-interchange with Middleman's build process

Tags: zurb-foundation, middleman, data-interchange

Zurb Foundation's [`data-interchange`](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html) works beautifully for me. In development.

But then I build and I end up with this sort of html:

```
<img alt='Why Believe' data-interchange='[/assets/images/logo.svg, (default)], [/assets/images/logo-square.svg, (medium)]'>
<noscript>
  <img alt='Why Believe' src='/assets/images/logo-e8f041ee.svg'>
</noscript>
```

Can you spot the problem?

Middleman's build process smartly fingerprints all of the assets, and links to the fingerprinted ones. No "un-fingerprinted" assets get built. I want all of that.

But the asset paths in the `data-interchange` attribute get no fingerprints. Therefore they work in development, but not once built and deployed.

How can I make it so the `data-interchange` asset paths also get the fingerprint? (And if middleman calls the `-e8f041ee` something other than "fingerprint", please let me know!)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use asset hashs then you should consider moving your images used by interchange to a new directory so they aren't automatically hashed. If you are not hosting on a CDN based setup, you should consider turning the cash busting hashes off.

For example I place images in source/blog/featured-images rather than /images/blog/... to avoid them being hashed for a similar reason (because I am defining the name via yml frontmatter.

Comment: I deploy entirely on a CDN, and love asset hashes.

Comment: In that case, I don't know of any way to get at those hashes without digging into the middleman source. I have also seen some examples of people creating their own hashing for middleman which might also be a good approach.